# Check if values from array are equal

Tags: python

Can someone explain why using the following code i do not get the message `Arguments len do not match` if not all the values are equal?

```
values = [len(self._parsed_arguments['inputs']), 
         len(self._parsed_arguments['files']), 
         len(self._parsed_arguments['names']), 
         len(self._parsed_arguments['types'])]

        print(values)
        if all(v != values[0] for v in values):
            print("Arguments len do not match")
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            print("what the hell")
```

Result:

```
[1, 1, 2, 1]
what the hell
```

Also tried

```
len(self._parsed_arguments['inputs'] != len(self._parsed_arguments['files'] != len(self._parsed_arguments['names'] != len(self._parsed_arguments['types'])
```

Comment: Why on earth would `all(v != values[0] for v in values)` be `True`? Did you mean `any`?

Comment: Your code works "correctly". You're testing if all values are equal in `values` which is `False` as you can see (`[1, 1, 2, 1]`) thus you land in your `else` statement.

Comment: @displayname actually it's checking if all values are different to the first value, which is `False` because the first value is equal to itself to start with...

Comment: `values = [1, 1, 2, 1]`, `[v != values[0] for v in values]` will return `[False, False, True, False]`, `all(v != values[0] for v in values)` will return `False`.

Comment: google De Morgans theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First way, already mentioned in the answers by Julien: `any` would be the correct, so write:

```
if any(v != values[0] for v in values):
    print("Arguments len do not match")
```

Another way (maybe more intuitive and depending on the size of the array also faster): check, if the length of the set is exactly one:

```
if len(set(values)) > 1:
    print("Arguments len do not match")
```